# python apache phoenix jdbc connection

Tags: python, apache-phoenix, jaydebeapi

I'm attempting to connect to Phoenix-Hbase via JDBC. Actually I already have a Phoenix connection through DBeaver and I'm trying to replicate it in python. I tried:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver",    
'jdbc:phoenix:host_name', r'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\phoenix-core-4.5.2-HBase-0.98.jar')
```

but this returns me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver not found
```

well, I double-checked Class Name, Phoenix and Hbase versions, but I noticed no anomalies. So I looked at DBeaver Phoenix driver settings which look like this, [a very long list of drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FemXb.png) that I really don't know [how to get them all at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoAcx.png) and eventually how to use them into code